# Как определить расширение изображения?

Tags: php

Есть следующий код, который предназначен для определения формата изображения.

```
if($_FILE["picture"]["type"] == 'image/gif') {
    $end = ".gif";
}
elseif($_FILE["picture"]["type"] == 'image/png') {
    $end = ".png";
}
elseif($_FILE["picture"]["type"] == 'image/jpeg') {
    $end = ".jpeg";
}
else {
    $text = "Формат файла не верен. Возможна загрузка лишь PNG/JPEG/GIF файлов.";
}
```

$end нужен для вставки формата в конце названия. $_FILES["picture"]["name"] не подойдет.

В общем, проблема в том, что вышеуказанный код не определяет формат изображения и получается, что изображение загружается без формата, только название. Как это исправить? Или тут ошибок нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В PHP есть такая прекрасная функция как [**`getimagesize`**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php).

Comment: А вот это самое верное решение.

Comment: Спасибо, опробую

Comment: Как определить РАСширение или разрешение. Может я что не понял.

Comment: @erofeev, универсальное же ж:

> Функция getimagesize() определит размер заданного изображения и вернет этот размер вместе с типом файла и текстовой строкой height/width, которую можно будет использовать внутри тэга HTML IMG, а также вернет соответствующий тип содержимого HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$extension = pathinfo(<path_image>, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Mime-type в массиве $_FILES определяется из того же имени файла.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/(.+)?\.(.+)?$/', $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'], $output); 
        $file = $output[1]; 
        $mime = $output[2];
```

Вот здесь расширение файла сохраняется в $mime .
Используйте эту функцию. Думаю будет удобно

Comment: Вроде получается как и в первом посте.

Comment: просто лучше не юзать explode. Ведь можно файл сделать **file.txt.php** 
И вот твой эксплод разобьет его на file.txt   и php . Ну а потом запустит скрипт.

Comment: Так же можно и загрузить file.gif, который окажется шеллом.

Comment: Пожалуй Вы правы. Тогда вопрос остается в силе. Мне тоже стало интересно улучшить свой обменник.

Answer (score -1):

Ну неужели так тяжело вбить в гугле **"Как определить расширение изображения php"** ? Чтобы вам выдало что-то вроде этого:

```
$type = end(explode(".", $path));
```

Comment: Ну после точки может быть и расширение .php и т.п.

Comment: А вам что надо !?

Comment: В принципе да, попробую, спасибо...

Comment: @Asen, не шути так, можно сделать .gif, залить на хост переименовать в .php и скрипт запустится, проверять нужно не разрешение а то что файл отдает...

Comment: И как делать то надо? Без проверки можно и шелл залить

Comment: Вы глупые? Вам @Asen скинул как получить расширение, неужели непонятно, что дальнейшие проверки подразумеваются, просто ему ни к чему их писать?  
@johniek_comp, это называется `Local include`, а никакое не переименование.

Comment: @johniek_comp, естественно, после этого кода, по логике вещей, должен следовать блок кода, проверяющий расширение( тип ) файла!

Comment: Расширение файла - это набор символов после последней точки (ваш КО). С типом его путать не стоит.

Comment: @neoascetic, расширение, по сути, это и есть тип файла

Comment: @Asen, с чего это? Если я сменю расширение с `jpg` на `exe`, поменяется ли тип, или формат файла (обратите внимание на запятую перед "или". Знаете, зачем она?)? В линуксах, например, чаще пофигу на этот "хвост", ибо формат файла определяется по т. н. "магическим" числам. Так-то! Если *по сути*

Comment: @neoascetic, да, и правда. Как-то не подумал об этом...